# Absolute path to lua script running on virtual machine

Tags: lua, virtual-machine

My Lua script runs on a virtual machine.

Physically the script file is on my laptop on disk C. Here you can see the path:

[image]

This is how it looks like on my laptop:

[image]

During work, script works with file **calendar_5min.txt**
I use line

```
f = io.open('calendar_5min.txt', "r")
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes I get errors because the script cannot find file **calendar_5min.txt**.
How can I write the absolute path to this file?
Something like

```
f = io.open('\\tsclient\C\_RollingMoonLua\calendar_5min.txt', "r")
```

...but with this spelling, it doesn't work.

Comment: `f = io.open([[\\tsclient\C\_RollingMoonLua\calendar_5min.txt]], "r")`

Comment: Thank you, it works! But ... why it works? What do the brackets do?

Comment: The brackets skip backslash interpolation. You can make it work without brackets, but then you need to escape each slash, so instead of `"\\ts..."` you need to use `"\\\\ts...."`.